# Is this logic incorrect? It seems to work for everything I try but apparently it is not right

Tags: java, while-loop, logic

So I have this program about a robber who walks into a bank. He finds N gold bars. He can carry M bars at a time and he takes T seconds to go between his car and the bank.

Input
3
3 2 10
35 68 42
25 70 1

First line is how many times the program will run/how many robberies.
First line of the first run (3 2 10), the 3 represents N, the number of gold bars. 2 represents M, number of bars the robber can carry at a time and 10 represents T, the time it takes for the robber to travel between his car and the bank.

Output
30
42
1

This was my logic to it but according to the graders of this program, it failed their test data (they have a different input). I tried many combinations of numbers and the answers still came out right. Does anyone see what could be wrong with this?

```
/* NOTE:   
1 <= First line of input <= 10    
1 <= N <= 100    
1 <= M <= 100    
1 <= T <= 100  */

public class Stealing
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (new File ("stealing.dat"));
        int numRuns = scan.nextInt();
        int time = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numRuns; i++)
        {
            int N = scan.nextInt();
            int M = scan.nextInt();
            int T = scan.nextInt();
            if (M >= N)
                time = T;
            else
            {
                while (N > 0)
                {
                    if (M <= N)
                        time += (2*T);
                    else
                        time += T;
                    N -= M;
                }
            }
            out.println(time);
            time = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't protect against bad input, such as negative numbers for `M`, which would result in an infinite loop

Comment: @Bohemian I don't think that is the issue, see the note at the top of the source.

Comment: If you are using, `M >= N` for `T` time, then the other logic should be `M < N` isn't it? Also `time += (2*T);` why is that `2`? T is independent of Gold...it's just a time between Vault and Car.

Comment: @bonCodigo M is the number of bars he/she can carry so if its greater than or equal to than the number of gold bars available, it should only take him/her one trip from the vault to his/her car. time+=(2*T) because if there are more bars than he/she can carry he/she would have to go back to vault so T is multiplied by two. T to get to the car, T to get back. You are right about it being M < N but either way since its in the else part, it has to be less than N. I received the same output when I made that change.

Comment: @bonCodigo Never mind about the M < N, that is what was wrong with it, I just didn't realize the reasoning behind it until now.

Comment: @OscarF mate, the `2*T` is still not a definite we can take. Unless we use `modulus` operator. `N % M` = 0 then you can take it as `1*T`else while you add `2` and keep checking the same in the while loop until N becomes 0. What do u think?

Comment: @bonCodigo The 2*T is fine in my eyes. Since the robber starts at the bank, if there are more gold bars than he/she can carry in one trip, it would take T seconds to get to the car and T seconds to come back for more gold. The problem was indeed with the if (M <= N) which should be M < N. After making that change, it worked perfectly. Bohemian's answer below explains it pretty well.

Comment: @bonCodigo see rollover at the end of my answer for why `2 * T` is OK. The answer is after summing `2 * T` you either subtract/add `T` if it is/is not an exact multiple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in your logic shows up when `N` is a multiple of `M`, for example the input

```
6 3 1
```

produces `4`, but it should produce `3`.

The problem is with this condition:

```
if (M <= N)
```

it should be:

```
if (M < N)
```

By testing for equality too, the bank robber makes one more trip back to the bank, but there's nothing to collect, so the loop ends (with her at the bank, rather than at the car - another logic problem).

If I were doing this I would *not* use a loop - I would use purely numerical methods (an exercise for the reader, but hover over the following to see my solution):

> `int time = (N / M) * 2 * T + (N % M == 0 ? -T : T);`

Comment: Thanks, that solved the issue. Good explanation but just out of curiosity, how would you go about doing this without a loop?

Comment: @Bohemian now this makes sense: your hovering has practised my first expression :D